# Accessing value of subclass property without instance

Tags: c#, generics, abstract

I am currently trying to save and load data for multiple classes to/from disk. I am using JSON serialization to read and write a text file with a custom file extension. This works perfectly fine.

However, instead of duplicating the code in every class I want to use inheritance and only have the save/load code once in an abstract superclass. I want to have a different file extension for each class.

Saving is not a problem, because I have an object, so I can simply use an abstract property, but when I want to load the data I don't, so I can't get the property value without first creating an instance of the type I want to load, which I find stupid.

Also, I can't make abstract static/const properties/fields in C# (for stupid reasons, don't even start), and I am out of good ideas.

```
//this is fine, although I don't really need the new constraint, but I keep it for consistency with the Load function
public static void Save<T>(string filename, T obj) where T : JsonSerializeable, new() {
    if (filename.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) filename = $"{DEFAULT_FILENAME}";

    string path = Path.ChangeExtension($"{DIRECTORY_NAME}/{filename}", obj.fileExtension);

    path = Path.ChangeExtension(path, obj.fileExtension);

    if (!Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_NAME)) Directory.CreateDirectory(DIRECTORY_NAME);

    File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None));
}

//this works, but I hate that I need to create an instance that has no other use than getting the property value
public static bool Load<T>(string filename, out T obj) where T : JsonSerializeable, new() {
    if (filename.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() || !Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_NAME)) {
        obj = default;
        return false;
    }

    string fileExtension = new T().fileExtension; //TODO -.-

    string path = Path.ChangeExtension($"{DIRECTORY_NAME}/{filename}", fileExtension);

    if (!File.Exists(path)) {
        obj = default;
        return false;
    }

    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(path));

    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, I could have public save/load methods in the subclasses, with the desired interface (i.e. without the extension) and have the superclass methods protected and there pass the extension as parameter. However, I still don't really like that. It is acceptable, and my current implementation (because creating a useless object doesn't fly), but is there a good way to do it with only the superclass functions? (and no, I don't want to use the class name as the file extension)

Note: As of now this is more of an academic question, since I have a working implementation, but this was only the latest instance of that same problem popping up in my programming over and over again, and I always find some kind of workaround. I would love to finally have a good solution.

Comment: You say *"I can't get the property value without first creating an instance of the type I want to load, which I find stupid"*. What exactly is stupid about this? Instance properties are specific to the instance. If you have a class property that is not instance-specific, then make it static.

Comment: Stupid is creating an object just to read a constant value (constant for that type) and then read a file to create a different object of that type.

Comment: If it's constant for the type, not an instance, then it should be `static`. If changing that is out of your control, then it does seem like a bad design. Like if we had to create a `DateTime` instance to get it's `MinValue`.

Comment: It can't be static, because there are is no abstract static in C#

Comment: It could be done with a non-abstract static property in the abstract class, which is then hidden in the child implementations with `new`. I'll add an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create an abstract class with a static member for the `Extension` property, and then hide that property in the child class implementations:

```
public abstract class FileType
{
    public static string Extension { get; } = "default";
}

public class PDFFile : FileType
{
    public static new string Extension { get; } = "pdf";
}

public class TextFile : FileType
{
    public static new string Extension { get; } = "txt";
}
```